# T-SQL Count days between two days (datediff not quite working)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

We have a requirement to bill our customers per day. We bill for an asset's existence in our system *on that day*. So, I started with datediff...

```
select datediff(dd  ,'2015-04-24 12:59:32.050'  ,'2015-05-01 00:59:59.000');
```

Returns this:

```
7
```

But I need to count the following dates: 4/24,4/25,4/26,4/27,4/28,4/29, 4/30, 5/1, which are 8 days. So datediff isn't quite working right. I tried these variations below

```
--too simple, returns 7, i need it to return 8
select datediff(dd  ,'2015-04-24 12:59:32.050', '2015-05-01 23:59:59.000');

--looking better, this returns the 8 i need
select ceiling(datediff(hh,'2015-04-24 12:59:32.050', '2015-05-01 23:59:59.000')/24.0);

-- returns 7, even though the answer still needs to be 8. (changed enddate)
select ceiling(datediff(hh,'2015-04-24 12:59:32.050', '2015-05-01 00:59:59.000')/24.0);
```

So, my question... How, in SQL, would I derive the date count like i described, since I believe datediff counts the number of day boundaries crossed.... My current best approach is loop through each day in a cursor and count. Ick.

Comment: select datediff(dd  ,'2015-04-24 00:00:00.000'  ,'2015-05-01 23:59:59.999');

Comment: Your assumption that datediff counts the number of boundaries is correct. If you want to include the start date too can't you just add 1 to the result? `select datediff(dd  ,'2015-04-24 12:59:32.050', '2015-05-01 23:59:59.000') + 1;` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `CONVERT` to get rid of the time part, add 1 to get the desired result:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,
                CONVERT(DATE, '2015-04-24 12:59:32.050'),
                CONVERT(DATE, '2015-05-01 00:59:59.000')) + 1;
```

It turns out the time part does not play any significant role in `DATEDIFF` when `dd` is used as the *datepart*  argument. Hence, `CONVERT` is redundant. This:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, '2015-04-24 23:59:59.59','2015-05-01 00:00:00.000') + 1
```

will return `8` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this which would return 8 days.

```
select datediff(dd ,'2015-04-24 12:59:32.050'  ,CASE DATEDIFF(Second,'2015-05-01 00:00:00.000','2015-05-01 23:59:59.000') WHEN 0 THEN '2015-05-01 23:59:59.000' ELSE DATEADD(dd,+1,'2015-05-01 23:59:59.000') END)
```

If you want to use variables for your dates then something like this would work.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
  DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
  DECLARE @EndDateOnly DATE
  SET @StartDate = '2015-04-24 12:59:32.050'
  SET @EndDate = '2015-05-01 23:59:59.000'
  SET @EndDateOnly = CAST(@EndDate AS DATE)

  SELECT datediff(dd ,@StartDate  ,CASE DATEDIFF(Second,CAST(@EndDateOnly||' 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME),@EndDate) WHEN 0 THEN @EndDate ELSE DATEADD(dd,+1,@EndDate) END)
END
```